# Truecrypt External HHD volume mounts but shows as unformatted

Tags: windows, truecrypt, headers

I’m away from home for two weeks carrying files in an external USB 3 HDD completely  formatted as a Truecrypt volume (HD is NTFS formatted I think). I can mount the volume in Truecrsaypt, so it shows up as a drive, but cannot open it. Windows claims it is not formatted. Tried it on 3 different PCs with different versions of Windows (XP, Vista, W7, with same result)

When I first mounted the volume, Truecrypt said the header was corrupt and I replaced it with the Restore Volume Header tool, with apparent success ie no errors reported. – don’t know if this is relevant)

I have a backup at home but need to access files here. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Windows XP does not support Truecrypt at all. So not sure how you even tried it on a Windows XP system.  It sounds like the header was corrupt and what you did has only made it worse.